# Antd Table Bug - Display duplicate rows, rows displayed exceeds the dataSource length

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am using Antd's table to render data and run into this bug which I can't explain why it would happen. The table would show one extra row with a duplicate value from one of the row members. This bug is not consistent which makes it harder to debug.

When console.log the data, it's length is 2, and the pagination on the antd table also shows 2 results returned. However, the table would show an extra duplicated row.

Below is my code snippet:

```
const data = (result || []).map((job: EvaluationResult) => {
        return {
            key: job.jobId,
            entity: job.name
        }
    })

<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} loading={entityEvaluationResultIsLoading} pagination={pagination} />
```

Comment: You got a duplicate key, the problem within your `data` not with the table.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. That was exactly what caused the bug.

Comment: @DennisVash but what if I show merged tables from db. Then it will have duplicates identifires. It is not data's problem, it is bug of table! It should show only rows, that contains at data, no amateur performance!